# return data ajax more than 2 values

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html, laravel

return more than 2 values from call ajax,

i have this code

```
 $('select[name="parameter"]').on('change', function() {
        var stateID = $(this).val();
       if(stateID != 'other') {
          $.ajax({
            url: "{{URL::to('myform/ajaxSO')}}/"+stateID ,
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {          
              $('select[name="so"]').empty();
              $.each(data, function(key, value , value2) {
              $('select[name="so"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
              });
              }
          });
```

controller

```
 public function myformAjaxSO($id)
{
    $cities = DB::table("kpi_parameters")
                ->where("id",$id)
                ->distinct('')
                ->lists("so_name","so_id","unit_name");   
    return json_encode($cities);      
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('myform/ajaxSO/{id}',array('as'=>'myform.ajax','uses'=>'QuartersController@myformAjaxSO'));
```

i want call unit_name on value2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists or Pluck return key & value from query. If you have more than one value, you may need to work around which I could suggest can use select method in your our query builder.

example controller method:

```
public function myformAjaxSO($id) {
    $cities = DB::table("kpi_parameters")->select("so_name","so_id","unit_name")
        ->where("id",$id)
        ->distinct('')
        ->get();

    return response()->json($cities, 200);
}
```

And Javascript Example:

```
$('select[name="parameter"]').on('change', function() {
    var stateID = $(this).val();
    if (stateID != 'other') {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{URL::to('myform/ajaxSO')}}/" + stateID,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('select[name="so"]').empty();
                $.each(data, function (key, city) {
                    $('select[name="so"]').append('<option value="' + city.so_id + '">' + city.so_name + '('+city.unit_name+') '+'</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hop this will help.

Comment: how to make data 'city' can use in @foreach ?

Answer (score 0):

you can return json and `JSON.parse(data)` in success handler